# Visual Studio 2022 packaging app - "Publish" for Store missing in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

Reviving an old Windows Desktop C++ project I made long ago in VS6, now running with VS2022 (Community version), App runs fine. Trying to get the App distributed via the Microsoft Store, created a developer account, a MS Partner account, paid the fee, registered an App name and id, etc.

The documentation [Create an app package using the packaging wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#before-packaging-your-app) suggests that right-clicking the project in the Solutions Explorer should display a menu containing a "Publish" entry, but not on my system. I see no "Package.appxmanifest" file either, nor can I find how to generate it. What am I missing?

This is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for a desktop app you need to **add a New Project** to your solution for Packaging, as described in [Part 5: Package and deploy with MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/modernize-wpf-tutorial-5). **That** will give you an entry Publish, and there you can also associate your package with the Store.